How do I remove the "d" node from the GET Response
My team provided me a GET called.  However, the response contains a "strange" d node.  I tried to ask them for help and they asked me to use XML instead (I know).  I am here to see if someone can tell why there's a d node and what we can do to remove it, so that I can deserialize the JSON response.  Here is the screenshot of the response I got:

UPDATE: The d node is there, because SAP uses ODATA 2.0.  So I ended up creating a generic ODATAWrapper to absorb the result.

What if you simpy consider the second level of the response? For example in Postman i would do it in this way: pm.response["d"] and I would save the response in an environment variable. You could do the same to deserialize the JSON. If the JSON module is a black box you can remove the d node and then feed your module. Instead if it is custom the problem is solved.

thanks, Antonio...your response inspired me to create an alternative solution.
